# Only displaying polygons over certain size in ArcMap using Definition Query?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, area, definition-query, expression

I have a polygon containing lots of bodies of water and only want to display the bodies of water over a certain size.

Can I do this using a definition query?

Comment: Do you want to just label bodies of water when they're over a certain size, or do you want to only show bodies of water over a certain size? Your question title and question imply the latter, but your code implies the former.

Comment: I want to only show bodies of water over a certain size. My code could be way off.

Comment: I was attempting to do it in the Display Expression box under the Display tab of the Layer properties in ArcMap 10.3. Is it possible to do it there?

Comment: @AnthonyStokes I am fairly certain that is for something different. What you want is a Definition Query. The Definition Query tab uses SQL not python functions like you have in your code example. Edit the question to use the term Definition Query and I can give you a full fledged answer:-)

Answer (score 7):

It is my understanding you cannot directly perform spatial queries in the *Defintion Query* tab. However because ESRI offers a *calculate geometry* option for common shapefile geometry calculations and automatically calculates area for feature classes, you can do a psuedo spatial query on a field containing the value of area for each polygon. **For shapefiles** the workflow is as follows:

- add a field to your feature class and name it, for example, 'Area'
- right click that field and select *Calculate Geometry*
- calculate area with with the dialog box that comes up. See screenshot:

[image]

- Then in the *Definition Query* tab use an expression like `"Area" > 50` to only show features larger than 50 sq m. See image below:

[image]

**For feature classes** use the automatically calculated field for area in a *Definition Query*.

Comment: Note that you only need to add the new field if you are using a shapefile. Feature classes have shape dimension fields that are automatically generated and updated with editing. And they are supported in def queries.

Comment: @Paul Thanks. I have updated the answer to include that information.